# appengine php app storing data in cassandra cluster

Tags: php, google-app-engine, cassandra, google-app-engine-python

I have a php app hosted on google appengine, this app receives data coming from sensors (the sensors send a json request using POST), the app gets the data, it performs a small etl process and then saves the data in a mysql db.

Mysql is falling short as currently I have 500+ sensors and more than 100M rows!
I will migrate to cassandra, but how I could send the data from the appengine php app to my cassandra cluster?
I can do this if I use a vm (php-cassandra connector is well supported) but I still want to use appengine and not worry if the VM in charge of receiving and processing data is down.

If php in appengine can't do this, I'm willing to try java/python.

Any clue how I could send the data from appengine to cassandra?

Comment: I've been trying to get something like that to work for over a week now (python runtime) but without success. Would like to know how you set it up. Can you msg me fakeer at pobox dot com?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Cassandra cluster is on an IP address that can be seen by app engine, you should just use the Cassandra PHP driver.

You will need to make sure your data model is proper for Cassandra. I have a video about time series data that may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1NtnrdIUlg0

Comment: Yes, the data model is proper for cassandra and the cassandra node can has a public ip, my problem is seems appengine doesn't have a php driver for cassandra.